# Import Sentry as module to the Chrome extension (manifest v3)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, import, module, sentry

I've been digging into the info for a while, so please read the whole question before marking it as duplicate. The question might be pretty trivial, however, nothing of what I've found helped me.

So, I want to add Sentry to my Chrome extension. I don't want to mess with CDN, so it's okay for me to download Sentry lib and store it locally.

I use Chrome Extension manifest v3, marked my background.js as a module, but cant properly import Sentry lib (or actually reach it, call its methods): constantly get an error

```
TypeError: Sentry.init is not a function
```

and in the Toolkit, Sentry is not even recognized as a module.

manifest:

```
  "background": { 
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "92",
```

background.js:

```
import * as Sentry from './libs/sentry.js';

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {

  Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://abcd@1234.ingest.sentry.io/666",
  });

  Sentry.captureMessage("test");
  
});
```

I've tried both
https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/7.14.2/bundle.js and https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/7.14.2/bundle.es5.js as `libs/sentry.js`

Here's repro sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IFWVn34-E0y6452n_jsCfBTAkaMicQJS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Both bundles aren't modules. They simply declare a variable. You can remove `type: module` from manifest.json and use `importScripts`, then access the global variable `Sentry` directly.

Comment: @wOxxOm In that case, i receive error `Error: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'chrome-extension://***/libs/sentry.js' failed to load.` Also, i still have some other modules, so I cant remove `type: module`. Is there an option to wrap the sentry.js into a module?

Comment: Use a different bundle or make a module from it yourself using `shimming` in webpack.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'd really prefer to skip the webpack for this project. Theoretically, its a simple import, but gives me a headache for a while. Thanks for the hint tho, will check the shimming functionality.

Comment: You can edit the bundle yourself and make it a ES module by adding the export keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [woxxom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom), i've changed sentry.js:

```
export var Sentry = (function (exports) { // added "export"
```

and used it as

```
import * as SentryLib from './libs/sentry.js';
*** 
SentryLib.Sentry.init({ });
```

Just a syntax note for future me, or someone else who might be stuck on something similar.

Comment: This was really helpful and it appears to work but I am getting an error in Chrome:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at sentry.js:2:1)`
Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: @JamesMundy i have to search for that project, but can you, for now, check if you have `"type": "module"` in the manifest?

Comment: I was going to write back to you but lost the thread - thanks for getting back to me. I found the issue, for me it was that I was not telling webpack to compile the file from typescript into javascript and was just copying it over, it is a JS file but I guess adding the export makes it a typescript file with javascript? I'm not completely sure but it all works now

Comment: @JamesMundy not quite: adding export makes it ES module, which can be imported. TS should be transpiled to JS, and clasp (i guess you use it) should support that out-of-box - or you can do it manually via webpack or babel. You should have tsconfig.json for that in any case.